# Jquery tools overlay , i can not close page with javascript

Tags: jquery-tools

I use this code ... http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/external.html

But I can not close page with ajax code. When I click "X" image page is closed, but I want to make this action with javascript.

I try to close page external-content.htm in external-content.htm.

`$(".contentWrap").hide("slow")` code is close page content, 
but it not close all page .

Comment: Have you tried `$('#overlay a.close').click()`?

Comment: Sorry, it is success, thanks...